# GridLine not visible in html

Tags: html, css

I have a table in which I have applied some css i.e.

```
table tr{
            border:1px solid black;
        }
```

The problem is wherever tr is empty the border is not being show. I have attached a snapshot. I need to know where I am wrong.[image]

Comment: try to give in inline style css

Comment: I have already given it inline css and also tried internal css style

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `&nbsp;` whereever value is not being shown.

Answer (score 2):

Using CSS, you can use just

```
table { empty-cells: show; }
```

in a style sheet, to suggest that all empty cells be displayed as normal cells.

Comment: Try this... `table td { border:1px solid black; }`

Comment: I have already tried that sir, actually i am making a table programatically, therefore by adding "&nbsp;" my issue is solved